# Action of $F_4$ on generalized flag manifolds

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, geometric-representation-theory

Does there exist (as elementary as possible) a generalized flag manifold (e.g. sphere, projective space, Grassmanian, etc.) of a simple classical Lie group (SL, SO or Sp over real or complex field), such that $F_4$ is acting transitively on it with stabilizer given by parabolic subgroup? In other words, is there a Lie group G (equal to SL, SO or Sp) and a parabolic subgroup $P< G$, such that G/P is equal to $F_4/Q$, where Q is parabolic subgroup of $F_4$ given by intersection of $F_4$ with P?

Comment: I don't think so.  Probably this can be deduced from the tables in Bourbaki.  But one reference which I happen to have on my desk is Cohen-Cooperstein, "Lie Incidence Systems ..."  If you look at their table, it seems that the type of coincidence you are suggesting does occur for $G_2$, but does not occur for $F_4$.

Comment: Your 'in order words' reinterpretation is not really a reinterpretation.  For example, $F_4^{(-20)}$ acts transitively on the $15$-sphere (the boundary of the octonic hyperbolic plane), which is a generalized flag manifold of $G$ any one of $SL(16,\mathbb{R})$, $SO(16)$, or $Sp(8,\mathbb{R})$, and the stabilizer subgroup of this action is a (maximal) parabolic subgroup.  However, none of these groups $G$ contain $F_4$ as a subgroup, so there is no equality $F_4/Q = G/P$ in the sense of your second sentence.

Comment: I'm sorry about the typos in the comment above, but there doesn't appear to be a way to fix them:  "in order words" $\mapsto$ "in other words", "$F_4$" means "$F_4^{(-20)}$" near the end, and I should have pointed out that this group also does not appear as a subgroup of $SO(17,1)$, which is the other maximal, connected, finite dimensional Lie subgroup of $Diff(S^{15})$ that contains $SO(16)$.

Comment: In the original question, was everything complex?  I remember this as being a question about complex Lie groups from when I commented earlier. 