# Automorphisms of homogeneous space $F_4/P_{\{\beta_2\}}$ over the exceptional group $F_4$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, lie-groups, algebraic-groups, homogeneous-spaces, f4

Let $F_4$ be the connected, simply connected, simple, complex, linear algebraic group of type $\mathsf{F}_4$, with Dynkin diagram
$$
\beta_1-\beta_2\Rightarrow\beta_3-\beta_4\,.
$$
Let $P_{\{\beta_2\}}$ be the minimal parabolic subgroup $\neq B$ such that its set of smiple roots is $\{\beta_2\}$. Let
$$
\mu\,\colon F_4\to\operatorname{Aut}(F_4/P_{\{\beta_2\}})
$$
be the obvious morphism which sends an element $g\in F_4$ to the translation $x\mapsto gx$.

> Is the morphism $\mu$ surjective? Or are there other automorphisms which do not come from the group? If there are more, how can they be described?

This [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/74660/action-of-f-4-on-generalized-flag-manifolds) and the [reference](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/238258649/download) given in the comments there seem to be related. But I can't answer myself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following paper says that your map $\mu$ is indeed surjective; the author attributes the result over $\mathbb C$ to Tits.

```
Demazure, M. Invent Math (1977) 39: 179. https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01390108
```

I also add the link

[Automorphism group of flag manifolds?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/160292/automorphism-group-of-flag-manifolds)

Comment: Thank you very much, @Venkataramana. I only see a preview of the link, and it can't be Proposition 1 what I am looking for. Can you elaborate where precisely I find the result in this paper, and maybe extract the information. It would be great for me.

Comment: I am talking about Theorem 1 ( Your case is $F_4$ and it is not exceptional in Demazure's Theorem 1).

Comment: Right, thanks again, here an open source link: https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN356556735_0039?tify={%22pages%22:[183],%22view%22:%22export%22}

Comment: Thank you , The open source link is indeed better!